# Finding the uncertainty in the estimate of a probability of a Poisson variable

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

For a Poisson process, $15$ occurrences were observed in $10$ minutes. The mean rate of occurrence was estimated as $\hat{\lambda}=1.5$ and the uncertainty of the estimate as $\sigma_\hat{\lambda}=0.387$. Find the probability of exactly one occurrence being observed in the next minute and find the uncertainty in the estimate.

The probability is easy, by the PMF it is $P(X=1) = .335$

The uncertainty is where I am confused. I understand I am meant to use propagation of uncertainty to find this, with

$\sigma=|\frac{dU}{d\lambda}|\sigma_X$

I find $U$ by substituting $1$ into the PMF and I get

$U(\lambda)=\lambda e^{\lambda}$

So the uncertainty is

$\sigma=|\frac{d}{d\lambda}(\lambda e^{\lambda})|\sigma_X = (e^{\lambda}+\lambda e^{\lambda})\sigma_X = (e^{1.5}+1.5e^{1.5}).387 = 4.336$

However, this answer doesn't make sense to me since I am finding the uncertainty in an estimate of probability. Shouldn't I expect the uncertainty to be a value between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: Should you be using $P(X=1)=\lambda e^{\lambda}$ or $\lambda e^{-\lambda}$?

Answer (score 0):

The ***next*** jump time $\tau_i$ of a Poisson process is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda\,,$ that is, $\mathbb P(\tau_i\in[t,t+dt))=\lambda e^{-\lambda}$ is the probability density of $\tau_i$. The probability that $\tau_i$ is within the next one minute is
$$\tag{1}
\mathbb P(\tau_i\in[0,1])=1-e^{-\lambda}\,.
$$
You estimated this $\lambda$ by $\hat\lambda=1.5$ (jumps per minute) with an accuracy of $\sigma_{\hat\lambda}=0.387\,.$ Plugging the values
$$
\lambda\in\{\hat\lambda-\sigma_{\hat\lambda},\hat\lambda,\hat\lambda+\sigma_{\hat\lambda}\}
$$
into (1) gives probabilities approximately as $0.67,0.78,0.85$. Thus, the probability is around $0.76$ within the range $0.76\pm 0.09$.